# Error in Running a script: Google Speech API

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, google-speech-api

I have been trying to run the following code from [this link](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-resources-python).

```
import io
import os

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types

# Instantiates a client
client = speech.SpeechClient()

# The name of the audio file to transcribe
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'resources',
    'audio.raw')

# Loads the audio into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()
    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=16000,
    language_code='en-US')

# Detects speech in the audio file
response = client.recognize(config, audio)

for result in response.results:
    print('Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
```

However, I am getting the following error when I run it using python 3.4.2 on a raspberry pi.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 10, in <module>
    client = speech.SpeechClient()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-   packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/gapic/speech_client.py", line 137, in __init__
credentials=credentials,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/gapic/transports/speech_grpc_transport.py", line 76, in __init__
channel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist- packages/google/api_core/operations_v1/operations_client.py", line 59, in     __init__
    self.operations_stub = operations_pb2.OperationsStub(channel)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OperationsStub'
```

I have been trying to get over this for about 3 days now and I have not found any solution.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still have the problem. I went through the same thing this morning.

I, apparently, seemed to have a version of `googleapis-common-protos` installed which was built without GRPC support (`1.6.0b6`). I downgraded it to `1.5.3`, restarted jupyter server and its working perfectly fine now. Please refer to this link.
[Google Cloud Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6282)